# Why is the mesh of a sphere (and other shapes) not clearly visible in Blender?

Tags: blender

The mesh of a sphere (and other shapes) is not clearly visible in Blender in Ubuntu. I have tried the same in Windows and it looks fine. Below you can see some screenshots of my problem on the mesh of a sphere.

- Before zooming in:

  [image: image with problem]
- After zooming in:

  [image: image after zooming in]

As you can see, after zooming in the sphere looks OK.

But why before zooming in does it look as if some parts are missing?